# Only one active thread after forking by Parallel::ForkManager. Why?

Tags: multithreading, perl, fork

I've got only one working thread after forking by Parallel::Fork:

```
ps -ef | grep ./BuildReportIndexV_VR2.pl

503      15955  9531 18 13:11 pts/0    00:02:06 /usr/bin/perl ./BuildReportIndexV_VR2.pl promt_tenant=AD backward=1
503      16102 15955 99 13:13 pts/0    00:09:29 /usr/bin/perl ./BuildReportIndexV_VR2.pl promt_tenant=AD backward=1
503      16103 15955  0 13:13 pts/0    00:00:02 /usr/bin/perl ./BuildReportIndexV_VR2.pl promt_tenant=AD backward=1
503      16104 15955  0 13:13 pts/0    00:00:02 /usr/bin/perl ./BuildReportIndexV_VR2.pl promt_tenant=AD backward=1
503      16105 15955  0 13:13 pts/0    00:00:03 /usr/bin/perl ./BuildReportIndexV_VR2.pl promt_tenant=AD backward=1
```

Process 15955 is parent, 16102 and down are children.

Here is the relevant code:

```
my $pm = Parallel::ForkManager->new($MAX_PROCESSES);
$pm->set_max_procs( $MAX_PROCESSES );

my $start_index;
my $last_index;

for ( $start_index = 0,
      $last_index=$start_index+$subhash_size-1;

      $last_index <= keys %$index_hr;

      $start_index=$last_index+1, $last_index=$start_index+$subhash_size-1
    )
{
    $pm->start and next;
    create_report_subprocess( $index_hr, $start_index, $last_index );
    $pm->finish;
}
$pm->wait_all_children;

print "After all children are waited: last index: $last_index\n";
if ( $last_index > keys %$index_hr) {
    $last_index = keys %$index_hr;
    create_report_subprocess( $index_hr, $start_index, $last_index );
}
```

I set $MAX_PROCESSES=4.

I expected that all 4 threads be running. Why only one?

Comment: these are processes, not threads.  so 3 of them are not using cpu; presumably they are waiting for something.  do you know what it is they are waiting for?

Comment: They are the same as the running process. No difference. That's the question: why only one of 4 equivalent threads took entire CPU?

Comment: what does create_report_subprocess do?  and after the first one finishes its work, what happens?

Comment: calculates values from (sub)hash, starting from $start_index and ending at $last_index.

Comment: no database or file interaction at all?  just calculations?

Comment: no; all values are in $index_hr which is hash reference; each of the processes pass over subset of the hash and calcs values.

Comment: I can't duplicate this; replacing the create_report_subprocess() call with `($x += $_) -= $_ for 1..100000000;`, I get all the processes reporting at 99% cpu (with 4 cores available), and in a 1-core vm they each report 24% cpu.  If you try that, what do you see?

Comment: ok, actually there is a connection in parent to Postgres DB. No access to DB is made in any of children.
Can it be a cause?

Cannot check proposed replacement: no access to server right now; i'll try it later.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting [AutoInactiveDestroy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DBD-Pg/Pg.pm#AutoInactiveDestroy_%28boolean%29) for any active database or statement handles before your for loop.

Comment: It did not help, but the problem was really in DB connection. After I closed DBI connection in parent process, all children processes ran on all CPUs. How should I handle this situation?

Comment: @rlib - read the DBI docs on forking - there's no practical way to share a single DB connection between different processes anyway.

Comment: I suspect you missed an active handle then.  Make sure your DBD::Pg version supports AutoInactiveDestroy, try turning on https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#TRACING and see what the child processes are actually doing.